# How to implement copy/past in mvp?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-recyclerview, mvp

I tried to implement a simple File Manager based on MVP pattern that support renaming,deleting or copying selected files.
I am struggling to implement copy/past feature in the right way.
Here is the UI:
[image]
what's the best approach to do that under MVP pattern?

Comment: Are you using any mvp library?

Comment: no, i implemented my own